# eliminate top space of a horizontal menu

Tags: css, menu, margin

I want to create a horizontal menu, which starts right on the top of the page, meaning I do not want to be any margin above it, but I do not know how to do that. I tried with `top: 0; margin:auto;`, but it does not work... my CSS code is right here:

```
.menu1 
{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     margin:auto;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }
.menu1 ul 
{
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 30px;
     background-color: purple;
 }

.menu1 li 
{
     float:left;
     margin-right: 10px;
 }

.menu1 li a 
{
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 8px 10px;
     text-decoration: none;

}

.menu1 li a:hover 
{
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **margin:0;** in **.menu1 ul**

and everything will be fine.

See the code below

thanks

```css
.menu1 
{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     margin:auto;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }
.menu1 ul 
{
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 30px;
     background-color: purple;
  margin:0;
 }

.menu1 li 
{
     float:left;
     margin-right: 10px;
 }

.menu1 li a 
{
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 8px 10px;
     text-decoration: none;

}

.menu1 li a:hover 
{
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu1">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html, .menu { margin:0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in style may it helps you

```
*{margin:0px 0px; padding:0px 0px;}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for how this answers the question. Giving everything a margin and padding of 0 using a rule that will be overridden by every other rule in the question doesn't appear to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1: `*{margin:0px 0px; padding:0px 0px;}`

2: Use Reset CSS